# grab value of custom attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to grab custom attribute like this 'something-20'

say for example it is in `<div class="somecustomClass something-20"></div>`

I want to grad the 19 so that I can manipulate it, because the css has block from something-1 to something-100

I used below code to retrieve tab id :

```
tabId = $('li').find('a').attr('href').replace('#tab', '');
```

is it the same approach?

Answer (score 4):

That's not a custom attribute, it's a class. You'd have to get the entire class string, then probably use a regular expression to find the value you want.

It would be easier to use `data-` attributes:

```
<div class="somecustomClass" data-something="20"></div>
```

JS:

```
var value = $('.somecustomClass').data('something'); // 20
```

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Woot! Wow, those are almost identical answers.

Comment: I can't do that because the style is in css, nothing to do with js, I want to grab the value for something else.. so I can just do like this? id = attr('something-20').replace('something-','');

Comment: No, `attr('something-20')` gets the value of an attribute called `something-20`. In your case, `something-20` is part of the value of the `class` attribute. If you simply can't change the html markup, you would need to get `.attr('class')` and probably use a regular expression to get the id from there.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to be a custom attribute I suggest you do what Jason said in his answer. But if you want to grab the `something-#` elements and do something with them you can do the following.

```
for(var i=1;i<=100;i++) {
    var el = $('.something-'+i);
    //do something with the element to manipulate it
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar.  What the tab id thing does is 3 things

Part 1 is selecting the right element.

Part 2 is getting the value of the attribute that contains the data we want

Part 3 is getting the specific bit of the data that we want with a regular expression

For part 1, I'm not sure what you're using to identify these blocks in order to select them.

You could have $('[class^="something"]') to get all the elements that have a class that starts with the text 'something', but that will be quite slow.  If you can use something like $('.somecustomClass') it will perform better.

If you just wanted to adapt the first matching element you came across, you could do this:

var myNumber = $('.somecustomClass')[0].className.replace(/.*?\bsomething\-(\d+).*/gi, "$1");

Apologies if you are already familiar with regular expressions, but for other readers this is a breakdown of what it does:

.*? means non-greedily select zero or more characters, \b means word boundary, then it finds the text 'something-' followed by one or more digits. Putting brackets around it captures what it finds there. Just in case you have classes after than, it has .* to get zero or more characters to find them too.  /gi on the end of that means look globally through the class and i means be case-insensitive. $1 as the second argument of the replace function is the captured digits.

Comment: nice answer! but regular expression is way to overload method. just to get some int value range from 1-100